# InstallShield LE forms, make new line in a text / picture

Tags: installshield-le

this is a newbie question.
i am using InstallShield LE on VS2010.
I have a value (text) inside identifier.

the text is being edited in one long line. without editing box.
how can i /n ?
Can i insert a picture ?

attach screen shot of the editing area:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn’t support line breaks in static text controls. During installation the text is automatically formatted based on control and font sizes.

If you really want a line break, simply use another static text control for the next line.